# Does the symmetric group S3 and the quaternion group admit a complete mapping?

Tags: group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory

I'm struggling trying to resolve the following problem:

*Determine whether the symmetric group $S_3$ and the quaternion group, of order 8, admit a complete mapping. If it is the case, build one.*

I know that a complete mapping for a quasigroup $(Q, \cdot)$ is a bijective function $\theta:Q \longrightarrow Q$ such that the function $\eta:Q\longrightarrow Q$ defined by $\eta(q)=q \cdot \theta(q)$ is bijective. 
I also know that a finite quasigroup $(Q, \cdot)$ has a complete mapping $\iff$ his table of multiplication has a transversal. 
I read that $S_3$ has not a complete mapping, but I can't find a way to prove it, can someone help me?

Comment: Suppose $\theta:S_3 \to S_3$ is bijective. How many odd permutations are there in the image of $\theta$? ...and in the image of $\eta(x) = x \theta(x)$? This is generalized by something called the Hall--Paige condition.

Comment: For $Q_8$, write down the whole multiplication table and just try to find one.